# Abrir txt con java

Tags: java, java-swing

Necesito abrir un un archivo txt pero desde la consola sino desde una aplicacion que abra txt, en el evento del boton se debe abrir el txt como si se estuviera abriendo desde el sistema operativo, utilizo GNU/linux (Debian)

si de algo le sirve busque en internet y solo me encontre con esto y asi fue mi adaptacion al codigo

```
try {
            ProcessBuilder p=new ProcessBuilder();
            p.command("/home/hp/Escritorio/ventas/reporte.txt");
            p.start();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Registro.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

pero me manda un error

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/hp/Escritorio/ventas/reporte.txt": error=13, Permiso denegado
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
```

gracias, espero cualquier ayuda o la forma correcta de hacerla

Comment: No soy experto en linux.. pero queres que lo abra que programa?? ahi es como si estuvieras ejecutando el txt..

Comment: Un archivo sólo se puede ejecutar si está marcado como *ejecutable*

Comment: @Pablo de una lo pondré

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no entiendo mal, quieres que un archivo se *abra* con la aplicación que tenga asociada por defecto en el sistema operativo. Por ejemplo, que un fichero txt abra un editor de textos para editar dicho fichero, un mp3 que lance un reproductor... etc.

En Java eso se hace con la clase [`java.awt.Desktop`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File)):

```
Desktop dt= Desktop.getDesktop();
dt.open("path del fichero");
```

Comment: Gracias Pablo esa era, me sirvió mucho